# Sencha Architect + Sencha Cmd - javascript error: e.onRedraw is not a function

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I'm building a Sencha Architect project with Sencha Cmd. To do that, I'm following the steps mentioned in [this forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246508-Setting-up-your-Architect-Touch-projects-to-be-used-with-Sencha-Cmd-v3&p=901360).

I created the Cmd project:

```
cd \path\to\sdk
sencha generate app app path\to\my\project
```

Then I edited `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>fresh</title>
    <!-- <x-compile> -->
        <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
            <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-compile> -->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

An then I ran the build:

```
cd path\my\project
sencha app build production
```

The first time it complained about `Ruby`, so I installed the version 1.9, and then it run with success.

In my production page I used `all-classes.js` and `resources/app-all.css`, both generated by the build.

The problem is that now I have javascript errors:

```
TypeError: e.onRedraw is not a function
TypeError: b.setOwner is not a function
```

How can I debug this process? Is there anything that I can do?

I'm using cmd version 3.1.2.342 with ExtJS ext-4.2.1.883.

**EDIT**

If I change the env to "testing", the new error is:

```
Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: series.column
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Cmd seems to not detect some xtypes and misses this classes in the generated code, my workaround is to use `Ext.require()` to add the classes.

This should be fixed in [3.0.0 Beta 2](http://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2.342/release-notes.html), but maybe some xtypes missed.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but do you happen to know how to use the Ext.require() and which libraries are supposed to be added?